# How to convert this C code to C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c++11

I have some arrays that are declared like this:

```
static double covalent_radius[256] = {
    [ 0 ] = 0.85,
    [ 1 ] = 0.37,
    ...
};
```

C++ doesn't allow this kind of declaration. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Nope. (ten-width-space)

Comment: ten-width-space is for SO to let you comment @Rapptz? If so, you can answer the question, if you like.

Comment: Wait, is this even C?

Comment: @E_net4, C99, yes. About the question, it's really probably better to just create a `std::array` and then fill in the specific elements you want different, but you *could* make a function that takes index-value pairs and uses some magic to initialize the whole array.

Comment: All right, I sure found the syntax odd from a C++ perspective.

Comment: @chris you are right, but since is just for local use, I want to do it with the less effort possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
static double covalent_radius[256] = {
    0.85, /* ?,  Unknown    */
    0.37, /* H,  Hydrogen   */
    ...
};
```

It's C89, not C99 so I suppose it should work.

Comment: "It's C89, not C99 so I suppose it should work." - not quite relevant, OP asked for C++, not C.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: C++ forked from C89, so there is significant relevance (but the code also is valid C++)

Comment: @MSalters What is "C++"? Is it pre-standard C++? C++98? C++03? C++11? C++14? C++17? The current and pre-current standards of C++ (C++14 and C++11, respectively) have C99 as a normative starting point. So, code written in C89 hasn't significantly better chance to compile as C++ than C99 code.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Designated initializers (in this example), compound literals and VLAs are available in C99 but not in C++.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Well, at the time C++ forked from C, there wasn't a C++ standard yet, so it's necessarily pre-standard C++. ISO 14882:1998 formalized the fork, but did so specifically for the library. The core language was a re-specification. C++11 and C++14 do use the C99 _library_ as a normative starting point, but again do not reference the core language.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you do this:

```
static double covalent_radius[256] = {
    0.85, /* 0: ?,  Unknown    */
    0.37, /* 1: H,  Hydrogen   */
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `std::vector` of a `std::tuple` of two `std::string` and a `double`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

static auto periodic_table = std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string, double>> 
{
    std::make_tuple("?", "Unknown", 0.85),
    std::make_tuple("H", "Hydrogen", 0.37)
};

std::string element_symbol(int neutrons)
{
    return std::get<0>(periodic_table[neutrons]);    
}

std::string element_name(int neutrons)
{
    return std::get<1>(periodic_table[neutrons]);    
}

double covalent_radius(int neutrons)
{
    return std::get<2>(periodic_table[neutrons]);    
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << element_symbol(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << element_name(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << covalent_radius(1) << "\n";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9baa239eae187222) (using C++11 initializer-lists).

**Note**: I'd make the periodic table `std::vector` instead of an array because they keep synthesizing new (unstable) elements.

Comment: There are few real-world objects which are properly described by an integer, but elements are - just the number of protons in the nucleus. That's a much saner key than names or symbols. (You see this with entry [0] which probably should be `'n', "neutron"`).